# Entity Framework Code First Text Store as Image in SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, binary-data

I have a legacy SQL database that has a linked table to store specifications for order lines.  The application designers use an image field in SQL to store the text as binary data.  I mocked up an example below:

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int LineNo { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineSpecifications
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int OrderLineNo { get; set; }
    public Image Bits { get; set; }   // <--- This Line
    public int Bit_Length { get; set; }
}
```

SQL Table Definition

```
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderID] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [OrderLineNo] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Bits] [image] NULL,
    [Bit_Length] [int] NOT NULL
```

Currently I have to use SQL with

```
cast(cast(Bits as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))
```

to extract the text and then perform the reverse to return it to the database.  Is it possible to have the conversion done in EF?  Perhaps at the property level { get; set;} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought.  I changed what was identified as an Image in SQL to a byte array (byte[]) and created a property (Specs) that processed the BITS values. Entity Framework was happy and it works in both directions.  Surprisingly easy.

```
public virtual byte[] BITS { get; set; }
public virtual int BITS_LENGTH { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public virtual string Specs
{
    get
    {
        UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
        string str = enc.GetString(BITS);
        return str;
    }
    set
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        BITS = encoding.GetBytes(value);
     }

}
```